# Autocomplete a field from URL

Tags: javascript, php, html

My URL is something like this: www.website.com/referral456

In the checkout page of my ecommerce I have a referral field that users have to manually complete with the referral number (in that case 456).

How this field could autocomplete itself directly from the URL?

Comment: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` returns all URL paremeters. You may explode it to an array and extract what you need

Answer (score 0):

Just get the current url or param passed (if your app has a router etc).

Then just strip all but the numbers from the string:

```
<?php
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/referral456';

$value = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

echo preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $value); //456
```

Then populate the field with it.

https://3v4l.org/F17g6

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function(){
    var param =  this.href.substr(this.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    document.getElementById('input#userInputField').value=param;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the url using `location.href` divide it using [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split), and selecting the second element (1) that is `referral454654654`, then, using [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace) you replace **referral** part with nothing. At the end you have only the number in `refId`. Here the example:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var refId = location.href.split('/')[1].replace('referral','');
    document.getElementById('input#refId').value = refId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
window.onload = function(){
    var getRefId = location.href.split('/')[1].replace('referral','');
    document.getElementById('input#refId').value = getRefId ;
}
```